Swaps on devnet with raydium
I have been trying raydium-sdk and raydium-sdk-v2.
I am stuck and can't find a way to test swaps on devnet,
specifically I can't find pools on devnet.
In the sdk-v2 I got it working with the raydium.api methods that dont work on devnet.
I have seen these so far
RAYDIUM SDK V2 demo :
https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk-V2
https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk-V2-demo
RAYDIUM SDK :
https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk
https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk-V1-demo
Any pointers or resources? Thanks
